# Backend sfGuardUser module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, sfdoctrineguard, sfguard

I use symfony 1.4.11 with Doctrine

I have sfGuardUser module in backend. I have sfGuardUserProfile table.

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    id:            { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    user_id:       { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    salutation:    { type: string(10), notnull: true }
    first_name:    { type: string(30), notnull: true }
    last_name:     { type: string(30), notnull: true }
    country:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    postcode:      { type: string(10) , notnull: true }
    city:          { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    address:       { type: string()   , notnull: true }
    phone:         { type: string(50) }
    email:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    validate:      { type: string(17) }
    banned:        { type: boolean, default: 0 }
    payed_until:   { type: datetime, notnull: true}
  relations:
     User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      onUpdate: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile
  indexes:
    user_id_unique:
      fields: [user_id]
      type: unique
```

SfGuardUser table:

```
GuardUser:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    username:
      type: string(128)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    algorithm:
      type: string(128)
      default: sha1
      notnull: true
    salt: string(128)
    password: string(128)
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      default: 1
    is_super_admin:
      type: boolean
      default: false
    last_login:
      type: timestamp
  indexes:
    is_active_idx:
      fields: [is_active]
  relations:
    groups:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: user_id
      foreign: group_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      foreignAlias: Users
    permissions:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: user_id
      foreign: permission_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserPermission
      foreignAlias: Users
```

I have next sfGuardUserForm:

```
  public function configure()
  {

      parent::configure();

  $profileForm = new sfGuardUserProfileForm($this->object->Profile);
  unset($profileForm['user_id'],$profileForm['banned'],$profileForm['validate'],$profileForm['payed_until']);


     $profileForm->widgetSchema['salutation'] = new weWidgetSalutationI18n();
       $profileForm->widgetSchema['country'] = new sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCountry();
       $profileForm->setDefault('country', 'DE');
  $this->embedForm('Profile', $profileForm);

  }
```

So, when I add new user  from backend, in my sfGuardUserProfile table **user_id = 0** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works for you:

```
public function configure()
{
   parent::configure();
   $profile = new sfGuardUserProfile();
   $profile->setUserId($this->getObject()->id);
   $profileForm = new sfGuardUserProfileForm($profile);
   $this->embedForm('Profile', $profileForm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is do not work( I can add new user, but in my form I have: `Notice: Undefined property: sfGuardUserAdminForm::$id in'

Comment: Thank you! but it is do not work... I found source of problem....I use sfSocialPlugin, and I make Edit `lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/sfGuardUser.php` and set class to extend
`sfSocialGuardUser` instead of `PluginsfGuardUser`. Do the same for `sfGuardUserTable`,making it extend `sfSocialGuardUserTable`...When i make by default it is all ok...hm...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but form the top of my head it's because you unset the user_id value.

Comment: when I delete unset($user_id), and I want to add new user, I  have field user , where I can choose existing user.

Comment: You choose your existing user with $profileForm = new sfGuardUserProfileForm($this->object->Profile);

Comment: @guiman I try to do this with this schema and form in other symfony project and it is all ok.But there are sfDoctrineGuardPlugin 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Somethings that first came to mind are:

- [Read this](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer) (to define a primary key, the keyword is primaryKey: true not primary: true and they dont need to be defined as autoincremental, ORM can guess it for himself)
- Dont unset the user_id or any ids of forms , they are hidden by default so that should not be a problem.

Check those poitns and see if he problem persist, if so i cuold be something not properly updated when changing the schema (remember always clearing cache and building all classes every time you modify your schema)

Hope this helps!