# sfSocialPlugin with sfDoctrineGuardUser

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard, sfguard, symfony-plugins

I use symfony 1.4.11  with sfDoctrineGuardUser 4.0.1 plugin and [sfSocialPlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfSocialPlugin/branches/doctrine) 
So, I have next [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254518/backend-sfguarduser-mudule) .Source of problem is sfSocialPlugin, and

`lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/sfGuardUser.php` and set class to extend `sfSocialGuardUser` instead of `PluginsfGuardUser`

When I make `class sfGuardUser extends sfSocialGuardUser` , I have problem, but when 
`class sfGuardUser extends PluginsfGuardUser`  all works fine.

I do not now why it is not work because :

`class sfGuardUser extends sfSocialGuardUser`

`class sfSocialGuardUser extends PluginsfGuardUser`

Thank you!

Comment: Were you getting an error message?  What was the problem?

Comment: user_id = 0 , this is was a problem. But it was a few month ago, so in last I do not use sfSocialPlugin plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in this function in  sfSocialGuardUser

```
public function getProfile()
  {
    $p = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('sfGuardUserProfile p')
      ->where('p.user_id = ?', $this->getId())
      ->fetchOne();

    return empty($p) ? new sfGuardUserProfile : $p;
  }
```

Without it, all works fine/